# Issue with CSS, HTML and background colors.

Tags: html, css, colors, background

I have the following issue.

I have 2 sets of checkboxes with a title for each. That title is supposed to have a grey background, then the checkboxes area should have no color in the background.

The issue is that if I put only 1 set of checkboxes with its title, the backgrounds work good.

However, when I put the 2nd set of checkboxes, the checkboxes area of the 1st set has a grey background and seems to be inheriting the bg of the title of the 2nd set.

Here is the code. Any clue?

Thanks!

```
<div class="bgFilterTitles">
    <h1 class="filterTitles">COLOR</h1>
</div>
<div class="boxes">
<?php
   $colors = $con -> prepare("SELECT DISTINCT color_base1 FROM item_descr ORDER BY color_base1 ASC");
   $colors ->execute();
   while ($colorBoxes = $colors->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC))
   {
     echo "<input type='checkbox' class='regularCheckbox' name='color' value='".$colorBoxes[color_base1]."' /><font class='similarItemsText'>   ".$colorBoxes[color_base1]."</font><br />";
   }
?>
</div>


<div class="bgFilterTitles">
    <h1 class="filterTitles">PRICE</h1>
</div>
<div class="boxes">
<?php
   $prices = $con -> prepare("SELECT DISTINCT price FROM item_descr ORDER BY price ASC");
   $prices ->execute();
   while ($priceSort = $prices->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC))
   {
      echo "<input type='checkbox' class='regularCheckbox' name='price' value='".$priceSort[price]."' /><font class='similarItemsText'>   ".$priceSort[price]."</font><br />";
   }
?>
</div>
```

Here are the CSSs used:

```
.boxes {
   width: 160px;
   float: left;
   padding: 10px;
   border: 1px solid #C6C6C6;
   clear: both;
}
.filterTitles
{
   background-color: #F1F1F1;
   font-family: Arial,Helvetica,Verdana,Sans-serif;
   font-size: 11px;
   font-weight: normal;
   color: #333;
   text-transform: uppercase;
   padding: 4px;
   border: 1px;
   border-color: #C6C6C6;
   border-top-style: dotted;
}
```

Comment: any chance you could recreate this issue with jsfiddle.net?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure if I understood the problem correctly, is this what you were trying to do?

http://jsfiddle.net/mdLVG/

In that case you need to add `clear:both;` to your `.filterTitles` CSS class.